# Button to selectively include content in an RSS feed

Tags: views, feeds

When creating or editing some content types I want to be able to have the option to add the content to an RSS feed thats generated by Views.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can just add a field to the content type(s) you are collecting with your view and use that to filter the rss feed. You could easily add a "include in rss" checkbox for example with whatever default value you like.

Comment: Good answer, and doing this with flags is also an option.

Comment: If you want to be a little lazy, you could also re-use the "Promote to front page" checkbox on each node.
Then, over on the view, simply add a filter for "Promote = TRUE"
Either solution is easily achievable. I'd be willing to give you a free and quick hand if you need. Reach me at dougvann.com/contact